# Java parent using childs overrides

Tags: java, overriding

Will `Parent.parentMethod2` or `Child.parentMethod2` be invoked when running `Child.childMethod1`?

```
public class Parent
{
    public void parentMethod1()
    {
        parentMethod2();
    }

    public void parentMethod2()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent
{
    public void childMehod1()
    {
        parentMethod1();
    }

    @Override
    public void parentMethod2()
    {
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: You will have `Exception` named by this site.

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` in every method to see what happens :) Normally `parentMethod1()` will call the overriden `parentMethod2()` if called from the `Child` class.

Comment: It will call `parentMethod2` from `Child`. So What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child method will be called (i.e. **the overridden parentMethod2)**.
This is the "normal" way inheritance works in java - your object **is** a child, so it will run the child's methods when they are available. it does not matter that we call parentMethod2 from parentMethod1, which is not overridden. the instance running the method is still a child

Answer (score 1):

`Child.childMehod1()` will call `Child.parentMethod2()`. meaning, your "//do something else" code will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

remember one thing

```
   public class Parent
    {
        public void parentMethod1()
        {
            this.parentMethod2();  //I have added 'this' here, ('this'  is implicit)
        }
    }
```

so 'this' is currently executing object which is child object. So child method will be called.